# How do I extract data from a calendar on a website using php?

Tags: php, calendar, extract, confluence

The website is Confluence. It has many things on the website one being a calendar. The calendar has events and such and I would like to extract those events and dates so that I can read the text I obtain to a user through with computer voice reading. Below is a picture of the whole thing.

If anyone is aware of Twilio I am trying to get callers to obtain information from the calendar.

[image: http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/2052/calendarf.png]

Comment: Questions are formatted using Markdown, see [Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to insert a picture.

Comment: Post a link to the website so we can see if it is easily parsed.

Comment: Or does the website offer an RSS / iCal / XML feed?  This would be parsed much easier than scraping the compiled HTML.

Comment: I want to know the same thing. Just a default events site, but I'm looking for a partly intelligent scraper to identify the dates and times and the title of the events

Answer (score 0):

I would use CURL in PHP to read in the HTML page and parse it using a HTML parser. But I would imagine the calendar you are referring to uses AJAX to fetch some elements in which case you can't do much scrapping. Look for an RSS or XML feed for the calendar.

Comment: I just took a screen shot and took only the calendar part out of the page, there is other stuff such as options etc on the top but i cut out just the calendar....Im frustrated but not giving up!